# node.js returning contents of a file using request module

Tags: json, node.js, request

I was learning how to read json data (for the [walkscore.com](http://walkscore.com) api) in Node.js and I found the request module. I know how to make it perform an action within the "request" block. However, I am calling it within a function and I want the function to return the json data. How would I be able to simply access the "body" variable inside the function, but outside the request block?

```
var request = require("request")

function loadWalkScore(lat, lon, address, name, state) {
   var address = encodeURI(address)
   var url = "http://api.walkscore.com/score?format=json&address=" + address
   url += "&lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&wsapikey=" + wsapikey

   request(url, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
      if (err) { return console.log(err); }
      // somehow make loadWalkScore() function return <body>
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to have `loadWalkScore` accept a callback argument, and call it within your request callback. When writing Node code, your functions rarely actually return the data you asked for, they'll either accept (and eventually invoke) a callback that you provide, or return Promises (which eventually resolve with the requested data). This is how to work with async operations like an HTTP request.

Possibly something like:

```
function loadWalkScore(lat, lon, address, name, state, cb) {
    ....
    request(url, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            cb(err);
        } else {
            cb(null, body);
        }
   });
```

Then call it like:

```
loadWalkScore(...args..., function (err, body) {
    console.log('body:', body);
})
```

Comment: My pleasure! And welcome to Stack Overflow. If you feel my answer was helpful, then click the green checkmark next to my answer. You can always change it later if someone provides a better answer.